# Credit Card comparison with mask using PHP

Tags: comparison, match, wildcard

I am looking for a simple and FAST way to compare a masked card number to an actual card number. For example, "4111111111111111" being the real card number and "4111xxxxxxxx1111" being my masked card number. I don't want to do any type of iteration as speed is my primary concern. Regex might be the way but I just don't have the Chutzpah to figure it out.

Comment: this will work... but not sure how fast it is yet..

Comment: function *compareCards*($mask, $cardNo) { 

 $cardChunk = explode("x" ,$mask); 
 $stripX = str_replace("x","",$mask);  
 $maskChunkOne = $cardChunk[0];
 $maskChunkTwo = substr($stripX, strlen($maskChunkOne)); 
 $firstX = stripos($mask, "x"); 
 $lastX = (strripos($mask, "x")) + 1; 
 $cardNoChunkOne = substr($cardNo, 0, $firstX);
 $cardNoChunkTwo = substr($cardNo, $lastX);
 if ($maskChunkOne == $cardNoChunkOne && $maskChunkTwo == $cardNoChunkTwo) {
    echo 'CARD MATCHES!';
 } else {
    echo 'NOPE... FAILED';
 }
}